# How can I link cells between two sheets so that value gets updated on the second sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a workbook with several sheets. I have dates on the sheets that i update to same value daily.

eg. on sheet 1, the date is in cell A1, on sheet 2, the date is in cell C2, does not follow a particular order but i update them to same value daily.

Is there anyway i can link the cells, so any change made in one affects the rest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other](https://superuser.com/questions/835301/mirror-cells-so-that-a-change-in-either-cell-updates-the-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on Sheet2 set the formula for C1 to:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

rinse and repeat for the other sheets.

edit- other option would be to make cell Sheet1!A1 a named range, and then in the other cells use:

```
=NamedRange
```

to define a named range in Excel-2007 select the cell you want to name, go to the Formulas tab and click on Define Name. Enter the desired name and press OK.

Answer (score 1):

Excel can do it for you automatically:

1. click Sheet2, click C2
2. press '='
3. click Sheet1, click A1
4. press Enter

Done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also concantenate the cells and this will update it, just go to cell C2 and click FX find formula concantenate and click back to A1 and just do that with all the tabs