# Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 cells containing the same picklist values on separate sheets. I want the cells to mirror each other so that whenever I choose a new value in either sheet 1 or sheet 2, the value on the other sheet is updated to match the newly selected value. Is this possible?

## UPDATE

- Worksheet 1:

  - Worksheet Name: 'Live Forecast Tool'
  - Cell containing picklist: C3:D3 (merged)
  - Picklist values within range: ='SF MRF'!H5:Y5
- Worksheet 2:

  - Worksheet Name: 'AH'
  - Cell containing picklist: C3:D3 (merged)
  - Picklist values within range: ='SF MRF'!H5:Y5

Cell C3:D3 needs to update to show the value that has been changed on the other sheet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel VBA code Private Sub Worksheet Change Power function not working](http://superuser.com/questions/700930/excel-vba-code-private-sub-worksheet-change-power-function-not-working)

Comment: That answer may solve my question but obviously the application is different and more complex. I don't have a good enough knowledge of visual basic to tell or adapt the code. Which question should I reply to, to ask for assistance?

Comment: If you can provide a set of rules and actual cell references (including worksheet names) then someone can write a quick routine (there *may* actually be two) that can get you started. So far, your question is far too vague to even start. Append your question with the additional information so everyone can see it without having to search through several comments. Hint: a Workbook_SheetChange event macro could reduce the coding to a single event macro.

Comment: @Jeeped Thanks for the advice, I've updated the question. I did a quick search for Workbook_SheetChange but couldn't see an obvious example of a macro that could be used for this, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: The solution would have to be something involving VBA.  If you did it with formulas, you would have a circular reference.

Comment: It's the same exact thing, when the target is in one range, match the other range.

Comment: Here's what my crystal ball is telling me so far: on either worksheet, the merged cells in C3:D3 contain some form of concatenated collection of the values within their own D6:D23. If the D6:D23 values change on one sheet, the C3:D3 on both sheets should change to reflect the change. Leave the values in the other sheet's D6:D23 alone. Is that close?

Comment: Almost :) so the cells in C3:D3 show a list of the values in D6:D23. When a particular value is selected from the list, the values in D6:D23 update. So C3:D3 shows a particular month & year. As a simplified example, D6:D9 might display June 14, July 14, August 14. When July 14 is selected the cells in D6:D9 update to start at July 14 and only show August 14..

Comment: Sorry, correction, the list displayed in C3:D3 is taken from another range, elsewhere in the spreadsheet. Values in D6:D23 increase by one month per row, from the month displayed in C3:D3.

Comment: @Raystafarian so I should change the question to ask for help adapting that macro?

Comment: It'd be a better idea if you tried using it and adapting it yourself and then come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: I've spent the last 10 minutes looking at the code and I have no idea where to start. I know it's a relatively simple macro but I have almost no experience editing these. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **AH** code area enter the following event macro:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("C3")
    Set r2 = Sheets("Live Forecast Tool").Range("C3")
    If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r2.Value = r1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

In the **Live Forecast Tool** code area enter the following event macro:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("C3")
    Set r2 = Sheets("AH").Range("C3")
    If Intersect(Target, r1) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r2.Value = r1.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, that's working perfectly. Since I posted the question I've added another sheet called AT. Is it possible to also mirror C3 for this sheet with the other two using this macro?