# How to Mirror Cells when the source is a data validation list? (Excel 2010)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, macros

I have a workbook with two tabs. The first tab is being used as a table for data validation lists I'm creating in the second page. For example, one list is called "Supervisors". This list starts cell N3, and down the column are 4 names. It looks like this:
[image: List of Supervisors]

The second page is an assignment sheet, with each list used several times to identify persons with different tasks. I created a drop down list using the data validation menu and selecting, for example, N4 thru N8 on Sheet 1 (Labeled Assignment Sheet Instructions). I then copied and pasted the drop down list I needed for each section. So far, everything went according to plan.
[image: Shift Assignment Sheet]

I want to build this into being able to provide assignments for multiple days. To save time, when a name is matched once to a task, I want that same name to be assigned across multiple days.

For example, If I put Carolyn in the first spot on 6/29, I want the page (printed page, not a tab or workbook) marked 6/30 to assign her name to the second spot, and the page marked 7/1 to assign her name to the third spot, and so on.

The tasks are all in static cells. When I tried doing a function to equal cell A4 with G4 (as an example), I got a #VALUE! message.

I looked through several forums and dozens of threads to try to piece together a solution, and from what I can gather, the copy function won't work because of the formatting in the originating cell. The best solution I found that *MAY* work doesn't explain the process of how to create a VBA Macro for me to understand the process.

This is the link for the thread I found that seems like my best option:
[Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other](https://superuser.com/questions/835301/mirror-cells-so-that-a-change-in-either-cell-updates-the-other)

I'm not asking that someone type up a VBA Macro tutorial for me, but if you can link a good one, and decipher that answer so I can understand how it applies, I'd be grateful. That is, if that will work for my situation. If not, any help in figuring out a workable solution would be great!

Comment: Show some Data, what did you write in your list, if your data is normal when you write in A16 =A4 it should write what is in A4 not #VALUE!

Comment: I updated my question with more relevant info and a few pics. Hope this helps clear it up!

Answer (score 0):

Reading your, question you want the assignees to cycle through the tasks, changing to the next position on each subsequent day. (I don't see how the "mirror cell" solution applies to your problem)

This could be achieved by creating a lookup table with each entry numbered in order.

```
   # Assignee
   1 Carolyn Burnside
   2 Ralph Henry
   3 Rondae Osborne 
   4 Codey Franklin
   5 David Kelly
```

Let's suppose this is in an Excel Table called [Assignees].

The allocation formula for the name above each of the assignment would then be `VLOOKUP(MOD(C1,5)+<assignment_number>,Assignees[#All],2,0)` with the `<assignment_number>` inserted in each formula according to the desired sequence.  Then just duplicate the sheet and increment the date and the names will rotate.   If you have more assignees just change the divisor in the MOD formula to match.