# automatically mirror =NOW value from one cell to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, microsoft-excel-365

I am using an excel file to upload data to a database. During the import specific cell values are entered to the database.

At a point during the import process the database looks for cell B31. If B31 contains a date-time value (yyyy.mm.dd. hh:mm), it will upload it.

I would like B31 to be the date and time retrieved by the NOW function. However I can not have the formula in B31, because the import process will give me an error.

Is there a way to have a different cell (C31 is fine) that has the formula =NOW, and somehow the value will be automatically mirrored to B31?

Thanks

Comment: If you do not want a formula in the cell, then the only option is vba.

Comment: How exactly are you importing the data? Is it done using Excel, or is some other product reading this `.xlsx` file?

Comment: Is the tool doing the import a tool that ingests the Excel data, and outputs the data in the required schema? If so, edit the tool to inject `now()`. If it's VBA, specify `now()` in your code, rather than reading it from a cell.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mirror cells so that a change in either cell updates the other](https://superuser.com/questions/835301/mirror-cells-so-that-a-change-in-either-cell-updates-the-other)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the work is done outside of Excel. If it were VBA, you'd surely have altered it to handle the desire by now.

If you cannot change the import process in the outside tool or routine, you only have one real option. VBA cannot help during an ongoing import done by a non-Excel family routine because it has no way to get its foot into that door. If you could arrange that, you could certainly arrange the much easier "read B31, if it has a date/time, then find NOW() in whatever your (the tool) language offers, replace the imported value of B31 with that, and keep on trucking."

An extremely reasonable workaround though, is to simply enter a date/time into B31. Use `NOW()` and copy the cell, then paste the value only back over it. Since seconds clearly wouldn't matter in that case, just typing a date/time of that, or something a few minutes (or whatever) into the future would be valid. Something reasonable.

After all, you just need a date/time there and want it to be right then, but a minute earlier or later can't likely matter one bit.

I recall someone asking a question like this a couple months back, maybe even re-asking it when he didn't like being told it can't be done by folks at the time. Pretty soon after, but Excel did not change in the minutes, hours, or day, so he didn't get happiness. It has not changed in the intervening time either, not in this respect, that is.

So, try the workaround. If you're doing nuclear weapons research and this would break laws of man and physics both, then insist to those that control the import routine that they fix their problem. Otherwise... this works.